# Actions on Google - Test my Project on my Android device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant, actions-builder

How can I test my Actions Builder project on an Android device (for example on my mobile phone)?

Can I publish my project and assign it to a device or a Google account? How I am able to use this Google Assistant project from this Google account?

Comment: Is this a conversational action (built with Actions Builder, Dialogflow, or the Actions on Google v2 API) or something built with App Actions (ie - an Android App that has some access through the Assistant)?

Comment: Conversational action built with Actions Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Actions Builder console, once you go to the "Test" tab, you will be able to invoke the Action on any Google Assistant device that is using the same account. If you've given the Action a name already, you can invoke it with "Hey Google, talk to *name of action*." If you haven't given it a name, you'd use "Hey Google, talk to my test app."

The test page gives you details, just in case.

[image: Actions Console Test page]

If you need to use a different account to test with, you can [publish to the Alpha channel](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases). With this:

- You can control who is permitted to access the Alpha version by adding them to a user list. (Up to 20 accounts.)
- You then provide them with a link to opt-in to the Alpha version. (They will need to access this link from chrome on a mobile device.)
- Unlike other "releases", this does not need to be approved by Google.

To begin an Alpha release

1. Select the "Deploy" tab along the top
2. Select the "Release" left menu item
3. Select the "Start a New Release" button
4. You will also need to add Alpha testers via the "Manage Alpha testers" link

[image: Release page]